# Node js. How to determine where the memory leak is?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I have node js process (1) with gramjs, telegraf, cheerio packages. For scraping, collecting information and save to the MongoDB and interact via telegram bot. Also i have 3 node processes for collecting information from a private node with web3 (2,3) and hardhat (4) for simulate transactions. All 4 processes interact with each other through express, i.e. each has a http server. Memory leak occurs only on the first, ~500 MB/hour. To identify the memory leak, I compared 2 snapshots, 1 before the leak and the 2nd after.

[image]
[image]
[image]

60k+ JSArrayBufferData with the 8192 size. PromiseReaction with 40k-100k distance and 10mb+ Retained Size.
Where to look next to understand whats means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was bug with gramjs lib and fixed

https://github.com/gram-js/gramjs/issues/439

https://github.com/gram-js/gramjs/commit/472c60c9c1ba1496f2260c5bac4e867cd2a24ecc